# LocalStorage and popup not working on a windows pc

Tags: javascript, popup, local-storage

I'm currently facing a really difficult bug on my code. This code works on my MacOS (on firefox, opera, safari and chrome) and also works on another Windows machine I have. However it doesn't work on a friend's computer using Windows, with Opera, Chrome or Edge.

**What the code does is:**

- A user clicks on a button
- I open a popup for a third party website
  that redirects me back to my site with a code on the url
- I use that code to fetch my server that fetches an api for the user info
- I receive that info on the popup and save it to localStorage
- The main window detects that there was a store event and displays the user information

**The bug can manifest in the following ways:**

- The popup is force closed (even if no windows.close function is
  triggered)
- Even if the data is stored in the popup and I can see it
  there, it doesn't show up on the main window storage

I have tried **postMessage** instead of **localStorage** and it works better than **localStorage**. Using **postMessage** the bug doesn't manifest itself using the private mode of Opera on Windows.

I tried using **Cookies** but they don't fit my use-case because I need to save the user image and it's too big for a cookie.

I also tried opening up a new tab instead of a window and the bug persists.

I have always cleared the **cache** and **localstorage**. I also had extensions disabled. Both the main website and the popup are on the same domain and protocol. The diference is the popup that is under /redirect?code=xxxxxxxx

Another weird fact: We had two different branches for this project on git: 'master' and 'develop'. Both published on heroku, and 'develop' had no bug on my friends pc. 'develop' was ahead of 'master' with no conflicts, we merged and the bug appeared on the 'master' website.

**page.js (the main window)**

```
function loginButtonAction(event) {

    window.open(fenixRequestUserPermissionURL, '_blank', 'width=750,height=675');
    fenixLoginButton.classList.add('is-loading');

    window.addEventListener('storage', function() {

        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fenix-user'));
        registerUser(userData);
        localStorage.removeItem('fenix-user');

    });

    event.preventDefault();
    fenixLoginButton.removeEventListener('click', loginButtonAction);
}

fenixLoginButton.addEventListener('click', loginButtonAction);
```

**popup.js (the window to which the first link redirects to)**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var params = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
    if (params.has('code')) {
        var code = params.get('code');

        fetch('/fetchInfo/' + code)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(received) {
                localStorage.setItem('fenix-user', JSON.stringify(received));
                window.close();

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    }

});
```

The bug is silent, there are no errors on any of the consoles. Thank you for reading until here!

Comment: I'm also confused about this issue, did you find the answer?